# Add opposite number of values in each key of nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to add a new element to each key of the nested dictionary. The nested dictionary looks like this:

```
nested = {
 ('0', '2'): {('2', '0'): 10.0, ('2', '3'): 159.0},
 ('0', '3'): {('3', '0'): 13.26923076923077, ('3', '2'): 10.5},
 ('0', '4'): {('4', '3'): 10.0},
 ('1', '2'): {('2', '0'): 11.0},
 ('2',): {('2', '0'): 10.0},
 ('2', '0'): {('0', '2'): 42.0, ('0', '3'): 109.0},
 ('2', '1'): {('1', '2'): 860.0},
 ('2', '3'): {('3', '2'): 223.8815789473684},
 ('2', '4'): {('4', '2'): 43.0},
 ('3', '0'): {('0', '2'): 69.5,
              ('0', '3'): 200.17391304347825,
              ('0', '4'): 507.0},
 ('3', '2'): {('2', '0'): 28.666666666666668,
              ('2', '1'): 64.0,
              ('2', '3'): 79.09859154929578,
              ('2', '4'): 132.66666666666666},
 ('3', '4'): {('4', '2'): 95.0, ('4', '3'): 1447.0},
 ('4', '2'): {('2', '3'): 71.5},
 ('4', '3'): {('3', '4'): 10.333333333333334}}
```

For each every key, I want to add a new key/value pair in the sub dictionary. The key is `key` in nested dictionary, but the `value` is the negative value of the sum of values in subdictionary. For example, for key ('0', '2'), I need to add a new key/value pair {('0', '2'): -(10+159)}, that is {('0', '2'): -169}, now the key ('0', '2') turns to be :

```
    ('0', '2'): {('2', '0'): 10.0, ('2', '3'): 159.0, ('0', '2'): -169}
```

I expected the new nested dictionary to be:

```
new_nested = {
 ('0', '2'): {('0', '2'): -169.0, ('2', '0'): 10.0, ('2', '3'): 159.0},
 ('0', '3'): {('0', '3'): -23.76923076923077,
              ('3', '0'): 13.26923076923077,
              ('3', '2'): 10.5},
 ('0', '4'): {('0', '4'): -10.0, ('4', '3'): 10.0},
 ('1', '2'): {('1', '2'): -11.0, ('2', '0'): 11.0},
 ('2',): {('2',): -10.0, ('2', '0'): 10.0},
 ('2', '0'): {('0', '2'): 42.0, ('0', '3'): 109.0, ('2', '0'): -151.0},
 ('2', '1'): {('1', '2'): 860.0, ('2', '1'): -860.0},
 ('2', '3'): {('2', '3'): -223.8815789473684, ('3', '2'): 223.8815789473684},
 ('2', '4'): {('2', '4'): -43.0, ('4', '2'): 43.0},
 ('3', '0'): {('0', '2'): 69.5,
              ('0', '3'): 200.17391304347825,
              ('0', '4'): 507.0,
              ('3', '0'): -776.6739130434783},
 ('3', '2'): {('2', '0'): 28.666666666666668,
              ('2', '1'): 64.0,
              ('2', '3'): 79.09859154929578,
              ('2', '4'): 132.66666666666666,
              ('3', '2'): -304.4319248826291},
 ('3', '4'): {('3', '4'): -1542.0, ('4', '2'): 95.0, ('4', '3'):1447.0},
 ('4', '2'): {('2', '3'): 71.5, ('4', '2'): -71.5},
 ('4', '3'): {('3', '4'): 10.333333333333334, ('4', '3'): -10.333333333333334}}
```

I use `dictionary.update` to solve this, but it didn't work well and replaced the original dictionary.

Comment: I notice your input and output dicts both have two instances of the key `('0', '3')`. This isn't possible for ordinary dicts, because keys must be unique. If you really need duplicate keys, then a dict may not be the appropriate data type for you.

Comment: it's a little messy, but there is only one instance for the ('0', '3'), if you could read it more clearly : )

Comment: Oh, good. in that case, a dict _may_ be the appropriate type for you :-)

Comment: @Miaomiao https://repl.it/repls/SwiftSelfishConnection my code works fine. May be your other parts of the code are affecting nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this.

```
for key,d in nested.items():
    d[key]= -(sum(d.values()))
```

---

```
for key,d in nested.items():
   print(f'{key} : {d}')

('0', '2') : {('2', '0'): 10.0, ('2', '3'): 159.0, ('0', '2'): -169.0}
('0', '3') : {('3', '0'): 13.26923076923077, ('3', '2'): 10.5, ('0', '3'): -23.76923076923077}
('0', '4') : {('4', '3'): 10.0, ('0', '4'): -10.0}
('1', '2') : {('2', '0'): 11.0, ('1', '2'): -11.0}
('2',) : {('2', '0'): 10.0, ('2',): -10.0}
('2', '0') : {('0', '2'): 42.0, ('0', '3'): 109.0, ('2', '0'): -151.0}
('2', '1') : {('1', '2'): 860.0, ('2', '1'): -860.0}
('2', '3') : {('3', '2'): 223.8815789473684, ('2', '3'): -223.8815789473684}
('2', '4') : {('4', '2'): 43.0, ('2', '4'): -43.0}
('3', '0') : {('0', '2'): 69.5, ('0', '3'): 200.17391304347825, ('0', '4'): 507.0, ('3', '0'): -776.6739130434783}
('3', '2') : {('2', '0'): 28.666666666666668, ('2', '1'): 64.0, ('2', '3'): 79.09859154929578, ('2', '4'): 132.66666666666666, ('3', '2'): -304.4319248826291}
('3', '4') : {('4', '2'): 95.0, ('4', '3'): 1447.0, ('3', '4'): -1542.0}
('4', '2') : {('2', '3'): 71.5, ('4', '2'): -71.5}
('4', '3') : {('3', '4'): 10.333333333333334, ('4', '3'): -10.333333333333334}
```

Comment: I get 0.0 for every opposite number in each key

Comment: @Miaomiao Can you post your code in the question. Because I copied the dict nested from the question and wrote this code and it worked for me.

Comment: Putting aside the issue of whether the result is 0.0, shouldn't it be `-(sum(d.values()))`?

Comment: @Kevin Totally true, formatting issues I posted this from mobile. My bad. Switching to laptop right now.

Comment: @Kevin Edited the answer. Thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: I got this: {('0', '2'): {('0', '2'): -0.0, ('2', '0'): 10.0,('2', '3'): 159.0}, ('0', '3'): {('0', '3'): -0.0,('3', '0'): 13,7,('3', '2'): 10.5},('0', '4'): {('0', '4'): -0.0, ('4', '3'): 10.0}, ('1', '2'): {('1', '2'): -0.0, ('2', '0'): 11.0},('2',): {('2',): 10.0, ('2', '0'): 10.0},('2', '0'): {('0', '2'): 42.0,('0', '3'): 109.0, ('2', '0'): -0.0},('2', '1'): {('1', '2'): 860.0, ('2', '1'): -0.0}, ('2', '3'): {('2', '3'): -0.0, ('3', '2'): 223},('2', '4'): {('2', '4'): -0.0, ('4', '2'): 43.0},('3', '0'): {('0', '2'): 69.5,('0', '3'): 200, ('0', '4'): 507.0,('3', '0'): -0.0}

Comment: @Miaomiao Not the output. Your python code.

Comment: for key,d in nested.items():
    d[key]=-(sum(d.values()))

Comment: I use your code, but I get 0.0 for all opposite number

Comment: Is `nested` output of a function?

Comment: @Miaomiao Check this link https://repl.it/repls/SwiftSelfishConnection .The above code works fine. So, there's issue with other parts of your code.

Comment: @Miaomiao Post you code in the above link I have given and click on share to generate a link and paste the link here. So, that other users can also debug your code. ;)

Comment: @Miaomiao paste your code click on share, copy the link given in share link.

Comment: it works!!!!!! Thanks

Comment: @Miaomiao Glad I helped you. Please upvote too.

Comment: i accept your answer, and thank you very much for your kindly helping